# Can't see service worker logs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, service-worker

Can't see logs of my service worker. Here are steps I tried to open logs for registered and running service worker.

1. Open `chrome://serviceworker-internals/`
2. Click Start and Inspect
3. Refresh inspect window
4. Wait for logs to appear

But, both `chrome://serviceworker-internals/` and ServiceWorker inspection shows zero logs.

However, source tab on inspect page shows latest code, which should print `console.log`
Here is the source code I am trying to see the logs of

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(payload => {
    const title = payload.notification.title;
    console.log(payload.notification);
    const options = {
        body: payload.notification.body,
        icon: payload.notification.icon,
        click_action: payload.notification.click_action || payload.data.click_action,
        link: payload.notification.link || payload.data.link,
        data: {
            time: new Date(Date.now()).toString(),
        },
    };

    return self.registration.showNotification(title, options);
});


self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function(event) {
    const notification = event.notification;
    notification.close();
    console.log(notification);
    const promiseChain = clients.openWindow('https://helloworld.com');
    event.waitUntil(promiseChain);

});
```

I am using Chrome  v68.0.3440.106, MacOS v10.13.6