# Angular-service-worker: Where are logs?

Tags: angular, debugging, logging, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

If you open `ngsw-worker.js` file, you will see some log commands like:

```
this.debugger.log(`Unknown version ${hash} mapped for client ${clientId}, using latest instead`, `initialize: map assignments`);
```

in its `Driver` and `IdleScheduler` class.

But nothing logs to browser console. Where are these logs?

---

I alse checked here: `chrome://serviceworker-internals/`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821735/cant-see-service-worker-logs).

Comment: That looks like a conditional log, which wont be printed all the time. May be you don't have version match scenario. Regardless, I couldn't imagine any place other than browser console to look for any log messages.